# Why intercept command is not not working on scala 2.11.7

Tags: scala

i am doing some scala exercises using the resources from [scala Exercises](http://scala-exercises.47deg.com/koans#maps) and i have found that intecept command is not working.

```
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:~ aironman$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val myMap = Map("OH" -> "Ohio", "WI" -> "Wisconsin", "IA" -> "Iowa")
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(OH -> Ohio, WI -> Wisconsin, IA -> Iowa)

scala> var blewWithException = true
blewWithException: Boolean = true

scala> intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
 |   myMap("MI")
 |   blewWithException = false
 | }
 <console>:13: error: not found: value intercept
   intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
   ^

 scala>
```

My excuses if this question is already solved, but the system is not retrieving me the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`intercept` method is a part of a test library, you have to download [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions) jar and extend `Assertions` trait to use it.

Comment: Including the whole ScalaTest for such a simple example is an overkill.

Comment: OP wants to find out why his code doesn't work, I explain it to him. And it's not an overkill at all when you learning, to use test library.

Comment: Thank you guys. ka4eli gave the response i was asking.

Answer (score 2):

Use try-catch statement, which is the native, proper way to catch an exception:

```
try {
    myMap("MI")
} catch { (e: NoSuchElementException) =>  
    // do whatever
}
```

Or avoid the exceptions altogether. Maps have `.getOrElse` method, which specify what to return when the key doesn't exist.

```
myMap.getOrElse("MI", "No state")
```

Or match on the result

```
myMap.get("MI") match {
   case Some(result) => result
   case _ => // do whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rok Kralj, from a novice with scala